# Extracting all characters before '\r' from a char*

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to extract all characters before the '\r' character from a char*.

The code below doesn't seem to work. I was expecting it to print "java,c++" but I just get an empty string as output instead.

```
char* testString = "java,c++\r\npython,go\r\n";
char* carriageReturn = strchr(testString, '\r');
*carriageReturn = '\0';
char* firstLine = strdup(testString);
*carriageReturn = '\r';
std::cout << firstLine;
```

What's the proper way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use `std::string`, and have to use C-strings, then you would need to use the functions provided in the `cstring` library, and do a bit of pointer arithmetic, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main(void)
{
  constexpr const char* testString = "java,c++\r\npython,go\r\n";
  const char* pch = strchr(testString, '\r');
  if(pch != NULL)
  {
    char substr[pch - testString + 1];
    strncpy(substr, testString, pch - testString);
    substr[pch - testString] = '\0';
    std::cout << substr << std::endl;
  }
  else
    std::cout << "String did not contain any carriage return!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> java,c++

In this example, you need to manually append the NULL terminator to your string, don't forget that (and don't forget reserving memory for that terminator too).

Answer (score 1):

You want to search for `\r`, which is the carriage return, not `r`, which is just the letter r from the english alphabet.

Moreover, why use C-string, when there is [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)? The C++ is the string class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  string testString = "java,c++\r\npython,go\r\n";
  std::string::size_type found = testString.find("\r");
  if(found != std::string::npos)
    cout << testString.substr(0, found) << endl;
  else
    cout << "String did not contain any carriage return!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> java,c++

Comment: It was a typo, I meant for it to be \r. Agree, it's preferable to use std::string, but this is part of a larger code base and they are using char* everywhere, so I'm trying to accomplish my task with as little code changes as possible.

Comment: @kpatelio gsamaras used *Empathy*, which made him post a C-string answer too! :) Hope it helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works well on VS2019. Just some cosmetical fixes:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char testString[] = "java,c++\r\npython,go\r\n";
    char* carriageReturn = strchr(testString, '\r');
    *carriageReturn = '\0';
    char* firstLine = _strdup(testString);
    *carriageReturn = '\r';
    std::cout << firstLine;
}
```